# Regarding Packer, can the /tmp directory be changed for the shell-local post processor?

Tags: linux, packer, hashicorp

Attempting to use the shell-local post processor to run a few commands after a build is finished. However, /tmp is mounted with noexec due to security. That isn’t really a problem, but upon remounting /tmp with exec permissions, the build fails with permission denied:

```
==> qemu.image_build: Running post-processor:  (type shell-local)
==> qemu.image_build (shell-local): Running local shell script: /tmp/packer-shell903509056
==> qemu.image_build (shell-local): /bin/sh: /tmp/packer-shell903509056: Permission denied
```

SELinux is in enforcing mode, but when set to permissive mode, it will still fail with permission denied. Here is the post-processor block in question:

```
post-processor "shell-local" {
      inline = [
        "echo 'Copying ${local.image_family}-${var.build_number}.tar.gz to the ${var.gcs_bucket} bucket'",
        "gsutil cp output/${local.os}/${local.os}_disk.raw.tar.gz gs://${var.gcs_bucket}/${local.os}/${local.image_family}-${var.build_number}.tar.gz",
        "echo 'Creating ${local.image_family}-${var.build_number} image'",
        "gcloud compute images create ${local.image_family}-${var.build_number} \\",
        "--source-uri=gs://${var.gcs_bucket}/${local.os}/${local.image_family}-${var.build_number}.tar.gz \\",
        "--family=${local.image_family}",
        "rm -rf output"
      ]
}
```

Is there a way to redirect where packer is writing these temporary scripts for the shell-local post processor?

Comment: This is `shell-local`, so are you prevented from initiating the Packer build from a different environment?

Comment: No, but I think I am just making this more complicated than it needs to be. Just tried setting TMPDIR and called the packer command. This appeared to have worked as the files that were getting written to tmp, were then written to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to set a value for TMPDIR, as packer just accepts the default location of tmp if another isn't set.

This allowed me to set another location for tmp and the successful execution of the process.

```
...
==> qemu.image_build: Running post-processor:  (type shell-local)
2022/09/26 19:53:03 packer-post-processor-shell-local plugin: [INFO] (shell-local): Prepending inline script with #!/bin/sh -e
==> qemu.image_build (shell-local): Running local shell script: /app/packer-tmp/packer-shell1371465973
2022/09/26 19:53:03 packer-post-processor-shell-local plugin: [INFO] (shell-local): starting local command: bash -c PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='qemu' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='image_build'  /app/packer-tmp/packer-shell1371465973
2022/09/26 19:53:03 packer-post-processor-shell-local plugin: [INFO] (shell-local communicator): Executing local shell command [bash -c PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='qemu' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='image_build'  /app/packer-tmp/packer-shell1371465973]
...
2022/09/26 19:57:39 [INFO] (telemetry) ending shell-local
2022/09/26 19:57:39 Deleting original artifact for build 'qemu.image_build'
==> Wait completed after 26 minutes 43 seconds
Build 'qemu.image_build' finished after 26 minutes 43 seconds.
...
```